# Pine Script Tradingview: How to prevent the chart from being compressed when the plot is too far from the price?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the Pine Script of Tradingview site, when we use `plot`, if the Plot is too far from the Prices, the chart is compressed, is there a way to prevent it?

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)
plot(2000, title='High', style=plot.style_line, color=color.new(color.red,10), linewidth=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it, there is no way to program, but it can be fixed from the tradingview settings.

1. Click the settings icon in the right corner of the chart.
2. Enable the `Scale Price Chart Only` option

[image]